# joomla database methods

Tags: database, joomla, bind

How do I use in case of Joomla the mysqli `bind_param`

how would this example should be declared using joomla Database methods?

```
...
$statement->bind_param('s', $like);
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: It seems that Joomla do not have support for mysqli_stmt class. https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/master/libraries/joomla/database

Comment: thank you for your feedback, I do not see as well any reference in the source. it seems like I have to use another workaround

Comment: For anyone on Joomla4 or higher, there are prepared statements.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22374054/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/63698230/2943403 , https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/12119/12352

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Joomla! 3.1, PDO/Sqlite and PDO/Oracle are supporting prepared statements, others are not implemented yet.

Given using a 'preparable' connection, it would work this way:

```
$db    = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('...')->where('...');

$query->bind(':s', $like);

$db->setQuery($query);

$records = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: Note that in 2016 they added mysqli and mysql prepared statement support.

Comment: You must be kidding.  I am talking about Joomla support.  https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22712/12352