# Joomla 3.1: accessing database from an external PHP

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, pdo

I have an external PHP script and I'm doing the query using PDO as such:

```
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE userName=:userName";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userName', $userName);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

As I am new to Joomla/PHP, I am not sure if this is a good practice.
Is there any security risk with my current set up? 
I just found out that it is possible to use JFactory in an external script, but I just
want to know if changing to JFactory is a must in my case, or I could just stick to using PDO?

Comment: Where does `$hostname`, `$db` and `$table` variables come from? If someone can edit their values, then you are gonna be in trouble.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459430/include-jfactory-class-in-an-external-php-file-joomla

Comment: Hi @Lucio, it is defined (hard-coded) before the try-catch statement. Should i define it in a different way? Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the link @Dasun, Actually my question is, is it fine to stick to PDO instead of using JFactory?

Comment: I googled it up but to no avail. Only came across an article which advice to use PDO instead of the avail framework, but didn't explain the logic behind it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this ,

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );//this is when we are in the root,means path to Joomla installation
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$app->initialise();
$db = JFactory::getDBO();// Joomla database object
```

For more about [Joomla database](http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase) usage ,[select operation](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase).

This is much better compared to explicitly providing DB name and host name.

Hope its make sense..

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I was wondering if its okay to stick to PDO or must I use the available framework.

Comment: when you are using Joomla you have to use framework standard instead of explicit connection. Joomla supports many PDO operations check this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812065/joomla-database-methods

Comment: Thanks Jobin! Appreciate your kind input