# How to use prepared statements in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

How to use Prepare methods in joomla model?
for example in pdo we use :

```
db->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl (`city`,`date`,`uid`,`title`) VALUES(:city,:date,:uid,:title)');
```

How can I do it in the Joomla!

Comment: Sadly, there are currently no prepared statements for Joomla. Lodder's answer below uses "the next best thing" to properly quote strings in the query.  This is [a related answer that speaks on security](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22712/12352).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Joomla, you always stick to the API which caters for the supported database types, like so:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$columns = array('city', 'date', 'uid', 'title');
$values = array($db->quote('value1'), $db->quote('value2'), $db->quote('value3'), $db->quote('value4'));

// Prepare the insert query.
$query
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__tablename')) //make sure you keep #__
    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
    ->values(implode(',', $values));

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
```

and for Joomla 3.x, you can replace `$db->query();` with `$db->execute();`

---

## Update:

As far as I know, Joomla 4 will use prepared statements in core. Here is a something I've mocked up, however have not tested:

```
    use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
    use Joomla\Database\ParameterType;

    $db = Factory::getDbo();

    // Your data
    $city = $db->quote('London');
    $date = $db->quote('21/01/2020');
    $uid = $db->quote(1234);
    $title = $db->quote('My Title');

    // Prepared query
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->insert($db->quoteName('#__tablename'))
        ->columns([
            $db->quoteName('city'),
            $db->quoteName('date'),
            $db->quoteName('uid'),
            $db->quoteName('title'),
        ])
        ->values(':city, :date, :uid, :title')
        ->bind(':city', $city, ParameterType::STRING)
        ->bind(':date', $date)
        ->bind(':uid', $uid, ParameterType::INTEGER)
        ->bind(':title', $title, ParameterType::STRING);

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->execute();
```

Comment: And what about if I want to use prepare statements in a query like SELECT * FROM a WHERE group = :group

Comment: @OceanicSix - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812065/joomla-database-methods

Comment: it is not working to me... "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':taste' at line 3 SQL=SELECT * FROM `food` WHERE taste = :taste". I am using MySQL, might be that the problem?

Comment: If you're having problems with your code, please ask a new question showing your code rather than commenting on here.

Comment: Is this a prepared statement in Joomla?

Comment: @RNKushwaha No, it is no prepared statement. It uses a regular statement. This syntax does not provide support for prepared statements. Maybe there will be support in the future but not now as far as I know of.

Comment: @Lodder you may like to update this one: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/12120/12352

Comment: Calling `quote()` is unnecessary on bound values, correct? I don't have a J4 installation to test with.  @Lod

Comment: @mickmackusa It's always good practice to sanitize values when inserting content into the database. Prepared statements don't 100% prevent SQL injection.

Comment: `quote()` isn't a value sanitising method.

Comment: "Escape" then, you know what I mean