# $params->set Array between square bracket

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3.0

i'm using K2 in Joomla 3.3.
I'm trying to set params (items ids ) to module k2_content from item.php file.
The result must to be between brackets, something like:

```
["96","68"]
```

My code is:

```
        $query = "SELECT   *  FROM #__k2_items WHERE  extra_fields_search = '$myautor' AND catid !=1 " ;
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $losautores = $db->loadObjectList();
        $result = array();
        foreach ($losautores as $key => $value) {
       $result[] = '" '.$value->id.' "';
       }

      $string_version = implode(',', $result);
     $autoresfinal = '['.$string_version.']';
```

If i test using print, looks ok.
But passing the var to pramas,  i get 1064 error.

```
$params->set('items', $autoresfinal);
```

To test I tried

```
$autoresfinal = ["96","68"];
```

And works fine.
Any idea why doesn't work?
Thank you.

Comment: Using square brackets like that is creating an array. You want it represented after creation with square brackets you can use json_encode to make a string out of it. I'm not sure I get your question though.

Comment: Sidenote: Wrap `#__k2_items` in backticks `\`` otherwise, SQL will think it's a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign `["x","y"]` you are assigning **an array**. Here you are transforming the array in a string.

Try simply

```
   $result = [ ];
   foreach ($db->loadObjectList() as $key => $value) {
       $result[] = $value->id;
   }
   $params->set('items', $result);
```

Also, if you wanted to convert the array into a string (possibly JSON), a faster and safer way is to use `json_encode` (with the appropriate [options](http://php.net/manual/it/function.json-encode.php)).

## UPDATE

The above remains true, but I had missed your complaint about *error 1064*. That is a [SQL syntax error](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-troubleshooting/error-1064) and it happens before you encode the results.

The reason - as noticed by Fred -ii- - is that in this query, `#__k2_items` needs escaping with backticks:

```
 $query = "SELECT   *  FROM #__k2_items WHERE  
             extra_fields_search = '$myautor' AND catid !=1 " ;
```

should be:

```
 $query = "SELECT   *  FROM `#__k2_items` WHERE  
             extra_fields_search = '$myautor' AND catid !=1 " ;
```

Also, you probably want to use **prepared statements** and parameterized queries (find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373852/how-to-use-prepared-statements-in-joomla)) instead of just plugging `$myautor` into a string. If you had an author called *D'Artagnan*, the query would become

```
....search = 'D'Artagnan' AND ...
```

which would again fail. Or if I called an author *' OR ''='*, the query would become

```
...search = '' OR ''='' AND ...
```

which, since '' is always equal to '', would match for *all* the records in your table.

Comment: `#__k2_items` table name can be used, just as long as it's wrapped in backticks, [`as per my comment to OP`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003280/params-set-array-between-square-bracket#comment40723850_26003280)

Comment: Thank you Very much!! Your solution works. (edited) Just for clarify :The query works fine with or without backticks. The error 1064 was solved with the correct array (thank you again), and i get the values what i need.  I will continue working around prepared statements and parameterized queries, like you suggest. Very useful answer.