# mysql insert query suddenly stopped working?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

The following query worked previously but now gives an error.

The error returned is `1054 Unknown column '$variable1' in 'field list'`

Using the code within Joomla and using the Joomla database connection to access a non Joomla database on the same server.

```
public function add_client($variable1, $variable2, $variable3){
    $db = $this->getDbo();
    $columns = array('field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5', 'field6');
    $values = array($variable1, $variable2, $variable3, '12', '24', '1');
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->insert($db->quoteName('#__clients'))
        ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
        ->values(implode(',', $values));
    $db->setQuery($query);
    if($db->execute()){
        return "The record was added successfully";
    }else{
        return "There was an error adding the record";
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of database connection are you using? I've never seen these functions before like `getQuery`

Comment: I'm betting `$variable1`, `$variable2`, or `$variable3` is a string, which needs to be quoted. You need to use a DB library that will use parameter binding.

Comment: Where do you set the variables `$variable1`, `$variable2`, and `$variable3`? And what database library is this you're using? Is this Joomla?

Comment: @aynber The error suggests that the variable name is being passed literally somewhere, where it expects a column name.

Comment: @Barmar I was hoping the OP had actually replaced the variable names, so I'm unsure if the error message was actually the name of the variable or the value of it. In any case, it needs to be quoted, or use prepared statements to prevent quoting issues. Of course, that wouldn't prevent issues where it was being passed literally, or column type mismatches.

Comment: @aynber He seems to be using Joomla, I hope it does proper escaping or preparing.

Comment: @Barmar Considering the error message, it doesn't seem like it, or the OP is doing it wrong. That's a MySQL error message, so whether it's passing the literal `$variable1` or a string, it's not quoted or prepared. The error is akin to `INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES (aynber)`, making it think `aynber` is a column and not a string.

Comment: @aynber Hard to tell. It seems like it's doing `INSERT INTO table (\`$variable1\`) VALUES (...)`

Comment: No, `$variable1` is part of the values in `->values(implode(',', $values));` So they're actually passing in the string of `"variable1_value, variable2_value, variable3_value, 12, 24, 1"` In any case, the OP hasn't chimed in in the past 15 minutes, so they've probably abandoned the question.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373852/how-to-use-prepared-statements-in-joomla), the values array needs to have `$db->quote` used.

Comment: @Barmar the error was the value of the variable

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to the variables being text this time when before they were numbers!

Solution below

```
public function add_client($variable1, $variable2, $variable3){
$db = $this->getDbo();
$columns = array('field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5', 'field6');
$values = array($db->quote($variable1), $db->quote($variable2), $db->quote($variable3), '12', '24', '1');
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__clients'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
    ->values(implode(',', $values));
$db->setQuery($query);
if($db->execute()){
    return "The record was added successfully";
}else{
    return "There was an error adding the record";
     }
}
```